# Mongoose doesn't save documents to my database locally

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My problem is simple as i guess.
i can run mongoose to save documents to my DB on mlab.
also can see the saved data via postman on get requests.
but when i use local mongodb instead of mlab then try to show the db collections on my terminal by running "mongo" then select the same db to which mongoose is connected
it shows me an empty db.
i try again to send post request with new data.. and the result is same, positive on postman and mlab, but when connect to local mongodb and post new data.. there is nothing there at all. the only way i can insert data to my shell is through the command insert().

Any idea why is this happening? 
Thank you in advance.

**app.js**

```
        var express = require("express");
        var app = express();
        var port = 8080;
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

        var mongoose = require("mongoose");
        mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
        mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test",{ useNewUrlParser: true });


        // Model & Schema
        var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
            firstName: String,
            lastName: String
        });
        var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);



        // Routes
        app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
            User.find({}, (err, user) => {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(user)
                res.send(user)
            })
        })
        app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
            var myData = new User(req.body);
            myData.save()
            .then(item => {
            res.send("item saved to database");
            })
            .catch(err => {
            res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
            });
        });



        app.use("/", (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
        });

        app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log("Server listening on port " + port);
        });
```

Here when i use mlab:

[image]

[image]

[image]

BUT when using local machine..:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: answer posted below. Please approve my answer if you like my work

Comment: is there a difference in mongodb version provided by mLab and your local db?

Comment: @Sridhar, I haven't checked yet but this should be very basic in all version, don't u agree?

Comment: @shireefkhatab yes. I agree. Checking the version, would give you some clue as to why fails

Comment: @Sridhar Both are running version 3.6

Comment: brother db.test.find() will not work, you have to do db.users.find() in terminal, because you have to find in collection. Since you dont have test schema it is not returning anything

Comment: Ratan; It worked!! . can you please write this as an answer explaining a bit more on the mistake/ solution so i can accept it and others can benefit too! Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like below in add api

```
app.post("/addname", (req, res) => {
    req.body = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body)); //This line is Optional, some time req.body is in json buffer form so we are converting to pure json
    User(req.body).save().then(item => {
        console.log("DB Item saved --->", item);
        res.status(200).send("item saved to database");
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
    });
});
```

dont forget that req.body must contain firstName, lastName

After your Question update regarding the listing of Collection(Schema) Documents

Your are trying

> db.test.find()

which will not work because Your Schema name is User and will save as users since mongodb prefer Plural collection names because it consists of more than One Documents

You must try

`db.users.find()` in your mongo shell

It will return all documents of User Collections.

If you want specific collection name(Schema name) then you have to create schema as below

```
// Model & Schema
var nameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String
}, { collection: 'User' });
var User = mongoose.model("User", nameSchema);
```

In mongo shell you must try like

```
db.User.find();
```

For listing all collection in mongo shell you must try like below

```
db.getCollectionNames()
```

Comment: Thank you, But unfortunately it didn't make any difference.

Comment: I have updated my answer try it once and send me feedback. do json stringify and json parse for req.body and try it once. awaiting for reply

Comment: Thank you for ur time and efforts.. but not yet really. i have updated my question and included some screenshots, have a look plz.

Comment: brother db.test.find() will not work, you have to do db.users.find() in terminal,  because you have to find in collection. Since you dont have test schema it is not returning anything

Comment: Ratan; It worked!! . can you please write this as an answer explaining a bit more on the mistake/ solution so i can accept it and others can benefit too! Thanks again.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please upvote and approve my answer if you like my efforts

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));` that should not be necessary if you have correctly setup the body-parser middleware.

Comment: yaa i know but i have just given hint if not working than apply JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));

Comment: I have accepted the answer because of the explanation about querying data on mongo shell. as for the code, thank you but i don't see anything wrong with the primary code i have written.. just not to confuse others. Thank you Ratan again.